# Access: Create n records with recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I'm trying something with VBA in Access but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

I have in a form a text control (numeric) where I can write some number. What I want is when I clic on a button in the form, cretat as many records in another table (not the source of the form) as the number in the text control.

I'm trying this, but it doesn't do anything:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Table")

If Not rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
    Do While rst.RecordCount < Me.Txt_Control
        rst.Edit
            rst.Fields("Field_01") = "Example 1"
            rst.Fields("Field_02") = "Example 2"
            rst.Fields("Field_03") = "Example 3"
        rst.Update
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
End If
```

Can someone give me a hand?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're editing one existing record, not adding new ones. Also, your code may run into trouble since you're opening a recordset with possible records present.

You can use the following:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 1=0") 'Open the table, but don't select anything
Do While rst.RecordCount < Me.Txt_Control
    rst.AddNew 'Add a new record
    rst.Fields("Field_01") = "Example 1"
    rst.Fields("Field_02") = "Example 2"
    rst.Fields("Field_03") = "Example 3"
    rst.Update
Loop
rst.Close
```